# Standards for reporting propensity score matching

Tags: logistic, modeling, propensity-scores

When publishing articles, there are international recommendations for reporting modeling such as the TRIPOD Statement ([Transparent reporting of a multivariable prediction model for individual prognosis or diagnosis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4284921/)) which include reporting items such as the calibration and validation, the closest relevant paper that I could find is:

Ali MS, Groenwold RHH, Belitser S V., Pestman WR, Hoes AW, Roes KCB, et al. Reporting of covariate selection and balance assessment in propensity score analysis is suboptimal: a systematic review. J Clin Epidemiol. 2015;68(2):112–21.

I have not been able to find any recommendations for what should be reported when having done propensity score matching. Are there any “best practices” for what authors should disclose about their methodology?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new standard for reporting different types of propensity score analyses, including matching, weighting, stratification, and covariate adjustment using propensity score. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28376195

This reporting guideline was recently promoted by Equator-network as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be journal specific, so maybe check if there previous publication in the journal which uses matching and use that as guideline.

I would suggest [this paper](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/matchp.pdf&ved=0CBkQFjAAahUKEwis1r-BwZXIAhWh33IKHYMpBI4&usg=AFQjCNGwk8iort_PQ3D7Xr9kAyNKs_T_0w) which in my oppion contains some very points about balance, I.e. what should convince the researcher (hence also the viewer).

Comment: Are you using a matching method that discards observations?  I would discourage that as it's inefficient and probably arbitrary and non-reproducible by others.

Comment: @Repmat your link was bad. Which of Gary King's papers did you mean?

Comment: I don't understand your question in regard to my answer, or to the question by OP.

Comment: @FTF. Try with this link http://gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/matchp-abs.shtml